# Does every pyramid has inradius

Tags: geometry

Does every pyramid has inscribed sphere? I know that every triangle has inscribed circular and I want to explore the analogy in 3D

Comment: Do you mean a tetrahedron? There are also two possible alternatives - one can try to find a sphere which touches all the edges of the tetrahedron, or alternatively a sphere which touched all its faces.

Comment: I know that we can inscribe sphere in pyramid with base square, hexagon... I want to know is it possible to inscribe sphere in every pyramid ?

Comment: If the base is a regular polygon and the apex of the pyramid is above its centre, there will be a point on the axis of symmetry which does the job for both tangent planes and tangent lines. However, this depends on the symmetry. There are other cases too, which are less easy to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

This will only be true for triangular pyramids (pyramids based on a triangle, rather than a square as for Egyptian pyramids).  It is the sphere of the largest radius, or the [insphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_sphere), contained inside the pyramid. The proof is a first variation argument.

Comment: I know that we can inscribe sphere in pyramid with base square, hexagon... I want to know is it possible to inscribe sphere in every pyramid ?

Comment: If your pyramid is a right pyramid on a regular polygon, then you can find a sphere touching all the faces.  However, in general this will not be possible, even for a pyramid on a rectangles.